# Bootstrap classpath not set

Tags: java, maven, java-7, building

I just upgraded my java to 1.7.0_60. I'm using maven to build my components. When I try to run `mvn test` on a component, I get this error message-

`[INFO] Compilation failure
could not parse error message: warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5`

I thought it could have something to do with `tools.jar` and explicitly mentioned them in my `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

But I'm still getting the same issue. In order to get rid of this what and how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling for Java source version 1.5, but you are using JDK 7 to compile. This means that the compiler uses the Java 7 class library to link you code, which may result in problems at runtime.

For example, if your code uses the `Long.compare(long, long)` method, the compilation will succeed, even if you set the target to 1.5, because at compile time the compiler checks the `Long` class (from the Java 7 class library) and sees that yes, indeed, a `Long.compare(long, long)` method does exist. However, when you try run this code on Java 1.5, it will fail, because Java 1.5 does not have a `Long.compare(long, long)` method.

Basically, the compiler is warning you that you are claiming that this *code* is Java 1.5 compliant, but that the Java class library you are compiling against may contain methods that do not actually exist in Java 1.5.

Comment: How can I fix this issue? Or is there a way at all?

Comment: The warning message I was talking about, this part: `warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5`, is just a warning. That should not prevent compilation. Maven is complaining that it cannot parse the warning. It could be that there are other error messages? I use maven 3.2.1, and it handles this warning just fine. Maybe try upgrading maven, or the compiler plugin?